# Vue files not deploying properly with django backend

Tags: django, vue.js, heroku, vue-router

https://github.com/Ubuntufoo/BrainTeasersSite

Vue(w/ vue cli)/Django app deployed to Heroku. Utilizing vue router. Everything works great on local machine in development. On Heroku domain the app and all django templates load fine, but static file request path for my vue files is flawed. See here: https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/anagram-game/ .

In console I see

```
GET https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/wordle-game/static/dist/js/chunk-vendors.58fb68d0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/wordle-game/static/dist/js/chunk-vendors.58fb68d0.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

My directory structure:

```
static (backend)
├── css
├── dist (vue build files output here)
│   ├── css
│   └── js
└── img
```

My vue.js.config:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: 'static/dist/', // The base URL appended to the top-level domain (https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/)
  outputDir: '../static/dist', // The path for where build files will be output, django side
  indexPath: '../../templates/_base_vue.html', // The path for the generated index file

  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      devMiddleware: {
        writeToDisk: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I think my vue router settings are impeding the resource request. My contact-us page, which is error-free, has a request of https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/static/js/home-styles.js. My 3 vue SPA's, which have unique URLs, now have requests such as https://brainteasers.herokuapp.com/wordle-game/static/dist/js/chunk-vendors.58fb68d0.js. My first sub-path of my top level domain includes 1 of 3 vue router paths, which properly directs django to the correct template but mucks up the resource request path. This is where I'm stuck, how to add a distinction in my settings for where the templates are found and where the static files are kept.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering, I found the answer is:

```
publicPath: 'static/dist/',
```

simply needs to be

```
publicPath: '/static/dist/',
```

When previously I excluded the forward slash, the GET resource request injected '/anagram-game/' between the tld name and the rest of the request. But when I corrected the public path, it is omitted. Perhaps it is a default action for bad request paths.